# Looking for C# registry class

Tags: c#, registry

Looking for C# class which wraps calls to do the following:

read and write a key value
read & write a key entry

enumerate the entries in a key. This is important. For example, need to list all entries in:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources

(I scanned through some codeproject.com registry classes and they didn't enumerate)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Microsoft.Win32.Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Use the standard C# / .NET registry classes and enumerate over the result of GetSubKeyNames().

See [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Development-Class/EnumeratingRegistryKeys.htm) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

Look in the "Microsoft.Win32" namespace.  There you'll find functions for creating and reading registry entries.

```
   Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey()
   Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey()
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you a lot have a look on this post
[Registry Iteration in C#](http://forum.codeproblem.com/c/i-want-to-iterate-subkeys-of-a-registry-key-using-c/)

Code is also included in it.