# How To Edit The Registy Values in Windows (the regedit) via Code in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, regedit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for C# registry class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104866/looking-for-c-sharp-registry-class)
>   [Way to write on registry location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927152/way-to-write-on-registry-location)

I'm trying to make a program in C# that boosts the speed of windows by doing a couple of things (clearing temp folder , prefetch folder ... etc)

but to make the program strong, I need to edit the registry values .. 
how can i do that ?

Comment: "Boosts the speed of windows" - okay... now, do unused registry values actually impair Windows performance? In what manner? Or is it just snake oil, as they say. I'm not alone to think that it's just placebo (if anything), e.g. see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproappcompat/thread/0407992a-b9b0-4f14-b9d6-7243ed21a110 for example - `Registry cleaning programs are *all* snake oil. (...) Ken Blake, Microsoft MVP (Windows Desktop Experience) since 2003`

Answer (score 2):

You may need to read this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C)

```
public string Read(string KeyName)
{
    // Opening the registry key
    RegistryKey rk = baseRegistryKey ;
    // Open a subKey as read-only
    RegistryKey sk1 = rk.OpenSubKey(subKey);
    // If the RegistrySubKey doesn't exist -> (null)
    if ( sk1 == null )
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        try 
        {
            // If the RegistryKey exists I get its value
            // or null is returned.
            return (string)sk1.GetValue(KeyName.ToUpper());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // AAAAAAAAAAARGH, an error!
            ShowErrorMessage(e, "Reading registry " + KeyName.ToUpper());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `else` in code like that is completely pointless (sorry, my pet peeve)

Comment: There is no way to `return null` without leaving the method, is there? So the `else` clause is redundant. It goes without saying that any code after `if (sk == null) { return null; }` will only get executed if `sk` wasn't `null`. It's still perfectly valid code of course, just redundant. It's only a matter of style. I personally don't like the extra nesting it brings along. I understand that some prefer to be more explicit about the intention though.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, it was excerpt of the article I reference in my answer, what I failed to understand was " (sorry, my pet peeve)".

Answer (score 0):

With the [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx) class.

Comment: Thank you, but could you provide an example..
I mean, how can i reach and change the MenuShowDelay value for example ?